# How to make different MAT-TAB share same HTML code

Tags: angular, tabs, angular-material, mat-tab

I have set of `mat-tab` in a `mat-tab-group`, the thing is they all share the same HTML code of a table which is being dynamically filled via functions which i am capturing on tab click event.

following is some code,

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="tabClick($event)" [hidden]=isPageLoading() [@fadeIn]>
    <mat-tab label="A">
        <HTML CODE>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="B">
        <HTML CODE>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="C">
        <HTML CODE>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

As i am already filling the tabs with this function,

```
tabClick(event: any) {
    console.log(event.index);
    switch (event.index) {
      case 0: 
      this.populateA('','1','999999');
      console.log('Author');
        break;
      case 1: 
      this.populateB('','1','999999');
      console.log('Form');
        break;
      case 2: 
      this.populateC('','1','999999');
      console.log('Location');
        break;
}
```

As you can see there is no need of writing that HTML multiple times, how can i share the same code for all tabs, pseudo-code will be like,

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="tabClick($event)" [hidden]=isPageLoading() [@fadeIn]>
    <mat-tab label="A">
    <mat-tab label="B">
    <mat-tab label="C">
        <HTML CODE>
    </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-template` for this:

```html
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="tabClick($event)" [hidden]=isPageLoading() [@fadeIn]>
    <mat-tab label="A">
         <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tabContent"></ng-container>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="B">
         <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tabContent"></ng-container>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="C">
         <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tabContent"></ng-container>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

<ng-template #tabContent >
   <HTML CODE>
</ng-template>
```

EDIT:

A working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yqdsr6 with the answer.

With multiple mat-paginator you'll have to use @ViewChildren instead of @ViewChild

I also had to tweak the imports in your app.module.ts

Comment: Almost worked, just one little thing, i am using `mat-table` with paginator, and this made paginator stopped working, how come? Maybe this is getting rendered after data is loaded?

Comment: By paginator stopped working, i mean the complete data is being displayed on table, which should've been broken by the paginator.

Comment: i dont see mat-table in the code you shared. could you update with the full updated code?

Comment: looking at the material docs, the mat-paginator needs to be directly after the table. so your placement of that matters. You could place the ng-template anywhere on the page .. just make sure that mat-paginator is directly after the table tag

Comment: I am placing it after the `table` tag, still the complete data is being displayed. From my past errors, this happened once when i was rendering HTML later, which forced me to use `hidden` instead of `*ngIf`.

Comment: what life cycle hook are you using for setting the paginator? try using ngAfterViewInit()

Comment: I was using `ngOnInit` and it threw on using `ngAfterViewInit()` that means i need to load the template after data is filled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201223/discussion-between-c-ogoo-and-mercurial).